# UnboundLocalError - Ultrasonic Sensor (HC-SR04) - Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors

I use two sensors. The code works for one but doesn't for another one.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO            
import time                        
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)                
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

TRIG = 8                                 
ECHO = 10
GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)                 
GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)

print ("Distance measurement in progress")
GPIO.output(TRIG, False)                
print ("Waitng For Sensor To Settle")
time.sleep(1)
    
def dist ():
    while True:
        
        time.sleep(0.1)
        
        GPIO.output(TRIG, True)                 
        time.sleep(0.00001)                     
        GPIO.output(TRIG, False)                 

        while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:               
            pulse_start = time.time()             

        while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:               
            pulse_end = time.time()                

        pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start 
        distance = (pulse_duration * 36320) / 2        
        distance = round(distance, 2)
          
        return distance

while True:
    print(dist())
```

[here:error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnspC.jpg)

I tried "global" but that time give me "Name Error".
Please give me another solution.

#### Okay guys here good news for me. (Own way solution)

-These sensors work with 3.3V so i connected two of them on the 3.3V pin on Raspberry. Because don't want the use a lot of diots on the breadboard.

**-I tried to connect one of them on 5V pin and other one on the 3.3V pin. It's works with this way.**(maybe it helps for who has the same problem)

-But still don't understand why. So is there any limitation for use 3.3V pins ?

Comment: This code is giving you the error? This would happen if the second `while` loop is never executed, but this is highly unlikely if you run the code exactly as above.

Comment: If `GPIO.inpu(ECHO)` does not return `1` (for whatever reason), then `pulse_end` is never assigned to. Add a `print('GPIO is 1')` to the second `while` loop, and we will see...

Comment: I tried your way. Yes, it never out from first loop. @Pythocrates